# How to make my async function await EVERYTHING?

Tags: javascript, async-await

If I run `putToDeath(0, 1).then(()=>{ console.log('done') }` the console outputs `done` before `setAsyncTimeout 463`.  So my function is not awaiting everything, it's returning prematurely.

How do I make it await until the very last function call, `face(exeNum, 'walk', true)`, is made?

```
async function putToDeath(conNum, exeNum) {
      let exeStartX = round(players[exeNum].x)
      let exeStartY = round(players[exeNum].y)
      console.log('walkTo 452')
      await walkTo(conNum, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, 0.5).then(async() => {
        faceAudience(conNum, 'walk')
        console.log('setAsyncTimeout 455')
        await setAsyncTimeout(async() => {
          let exe = players[exeNum]
          let direction = pointDirection(exe.x, exe.y, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2)
          let distance = lineLength(exe.x, exe.y, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2)
          let dest = getLineEndpoint(exe.x, exe.y, direction, distance - 50)
          console.log('walkTo 461')
          await walkTo(exeNum, dest.x, dest.y, 0.75).then(async() => {
          console.log('setAsyncTimeout 463')
            await setAsyncTimeout(async() => {
              swingSword(exeNum)
              await setAsyncTimeout(async() => {
                await die(conNum).then(async() => {
                  await setAsyncTimeout(async() => {
                    face(exeNum, 'walk', false)
                    await setAsyncTimeout(async() => {
                      await walkTo(exeNum, exeStartX, exeStartY, 0.75).then(async() => {
                        face(exeNum, 'walk', true)
                      })
                    }, 500)
                  }, 500)
                })
              }, 750)
            }, 500)
          })
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
```

```
const setAsyncTimeout = (cb, timeout = 0) => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb()
        resolve()
      }, timeout)
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to mix callbacks and Promises. There is also no need to mix `.then` and `await`. Turn your promising timer into:

```
const setAsyncTimeout = (timeout = 0) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve()
  }, timeout)
});
```

Then use it as:

```
await walkTo(conNum, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, 0.5);
faceAudience(conNum, 'walk')
console.log('setAsyncTimeout 455')    
await setAsyncTimeout(1000);

swingSword(exeNum);
await setAsyncTimeout(1000);

await die(conNum);
await setAsyncTimeout(1000);

face(exeNum, 'walk', false);
await setAsyncTimeout(1000);

await walkTo(exeNum, exeStartX, exeStartY, 0.75);
face(exeNum, 'walk', true);
```

Comment: Awesome!  This allowed me to make all the rest of my code more readable as well.

Comment: I wanted to ask how to execute an array of async function calls in series (one after the other), NOT in parallel, not simultaneously.  `await f(0); await f(1)` works but `;[0, 1].forEach(i => { await f(i) })` executes both calls at once.  I want them done in order, not moving to the next until the first is complete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Don't know why you are banned, probably not because of this post. If you think the ban is incorrect (!= unfair) flag for a moderator, they can tell you why that happened.

Comment: Thanks, `for ... of` does exactly what I want to do.  I am certain it's because of this question because I haven't posted in a long time, then I post this and bam, banned within 3 hours.  Apparently there is a zero reinstatement policy so I gain nothing from inquiring further.

Comment: Thanks I do admit I'm curious as to what happened.